# how to enable PreventUserExistenceErrors in cognito from terrafom

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

[image: app client user pool detail]

I need to enable `Prevent User Existence Errors` from terraform.

Comment: You can't do that yet. It also looks like there's not an existing feature request for it so you should ask for that at https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues

Comment: yes, i already did that when i couldn't find its definition on the provider.
https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/11340.
Please do upvote the issue. - Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since tarraform version [2.54.0](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/2.54.0/docs/resources/cognito_user_pool_client#prevent_user_existence_errors) this feature is available with the `prevent_user_existence_errors` attribute, the possible values are: `ENABLE` or `LEGACY`.
Example:

```
resource "aws_cognito_user_pool" "pool" {
  name = "pool"
}

resource "aws_cognito_user_pool_client" "client" {
  name = "client"

  user_pool_id = aws_cognito_user_pool.pool.id

  prevent_user_existence_errors = "ENABLED"
}
```